# Vertical centering of text within block bootstrap button

Tags: html, css

I'm going through freecode camp to learn coding and am working on my personal portfolio page here (https://codepen.io/DerekDenHartigh/pen/ypgvKV) I've got buttons at the top and I'm having a really hard time modifying the text - I had to use **HTML** *h2* element to get the right size font because none of my **CSS** would apply to it. Now I'd like to vertically center the text but am not sure how.  Thanks!

```
body{
    background-color: lightgrey
}

#Banner{
    height: 70px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 5px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

button{
    height: 60px;
    background-color: grey;
    font-size: 20px;
}

button:hover {
    background-color:   #D2B48C;
    color: white;
}

#bAboutMe{
    width:calc(100%/3);
    background-color: grey;
}

#bProgrammingProficiencies{
    width:calc(100%/3);
    background-color: grey;
    border-left: 5px solid black;
    border-right: 5px solid black;
}

#bContcactInfo{
    width:calc(100%/3);
    background-color: grey;
}

<div class="row" id="Banner">
    <div class=column id="bAboutMe">
        <button class="btn btn-block"><h2>About Me</h2></button>
    </div>
    <div class=column id="bProgrammingProficiencies">
        <button class="btn btn-block"><h2>Programming Proficiencies</h2></button>
    </div>
    <div class=column id="bContcactInfo">
        <button class="btn btn-block"><h2>Contact Information</h2></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `<h2>` are applied css bootstrap with `margin-top:20px; margin-bottom:10px`. U just need to set these two to 0

```
h2 {
 margin:0;
}
```

or

```
h2{
 margin-top:0;
 margin-bottom:0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I'll need to target it more specifically with id's I think but this is exactly the info I needed!  Sorry my up-vote doesn't count yet :)